# Macro to Remove Just the Heading style in word vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a word document that was converted from a pdf. I'm trying to remove certain level 1 headings in the document, the problem is that I want to maintain the other styles. For instance, I have multiple headings that are bullet points, and I just want to remove the heading style and maintain the bullet point and bold styles. Is there a way to do this in VBA?

Comment: If the style is Heading 1 (as an example), that style is not deleteable. So in that case, it's not possible. If you delete a style, _all_ formatting goes with it, including bolding and bullets. Let the user interface be your guide: if you can't do it in the program, you can't do it in VBA either.

Comment: You can use Find and Replace to remove text in a certain style. No programming needed.